# Test data snapshot using liquibase

Tags: liquibase, snapshot, test-data

I have a very basic knowledge on liquibase.My project team is planning to use Liquibase for Test data snapshot. we have a cloud database (Postgresql) for different microservices. we have planned to take Test data snap before scripts execution and roll back the original state after the execution. Any insights on this would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase has this capability which is a Pro feature. You can use `liquibase rollbackToUpdate` feature to rollback the database state to a specific deployment ID. Read more about the rollback Pro features here: https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/pro/rollbackoneupdate.html

NOTE: Before running the `liquibase rollbackToUpdate`, make sure to view the SQL log output of what all will be rolled back. You need to use `liquibase rollbackTpUpdateSQL` to get the log output in SQL format. https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/pro/rollbackoneupdatesql.html

Comment: Unfortunately we are using only the base version of liquibase !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **context** attribut of liquibase, context = dev, test, faker.....

in producton you must execute liquibase with another context for skipping fake-data.

Comment: <changeSet id="20210803090709" author="smak" context="faker">

Comment: Thanks for providing some insights! But my requirement to take test data snapshot of current state and then roll back this state in future.. Is it something achievable in liquibase??

Comment: You can use also labels attribut : https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/labels.html

Comment: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html